# Keeping a bundled realm up to date using REST

Tags: ios, swift, rest, realm

I have an app that uses a database of about 5000 entries.
This database is bundled in the app as a realm file.
I want to be able to update/add entries to this database regulary using REST and I think I have done it correctly - I just want to make sure.
This is how I have done it:

When the app is installed I copy the bundled database from the mainBundle to the Documents directory for read/write access. I then delete the database from the mainBundle.

When I update/add new entries to the database, they are pushed to the user using REST and inserted into the database located in the Documents directory.

When an update is released of the app, I make a check to see if the database already exists in the Documents folder - if it does I automatically remove the database in the mainBundle as it is not needed.

Am I on the right track with this? Is there a better way of doing it?

Appreciate any input!

Regards,
Erik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I update/add new entries to the database, they are pushed to the user using REST and inserted into the database located in the Documents directory.

Technically, you can't push via REST. So I guess, you're either sending a background push notification to all installations or you're checking at application launch, whether there is a new version of the database available. That's at least what I would propose, but your requirements for getting new data out may vary.

> When an update is released of the app, I make a check to see if the database already exists in the Documents folder - if it does I automatically remove the database in the mainBundle as it is not needed.

This doesn't work. The main bundle is the signed app bundle. If you would tamper the contents, that would prevent your app from launching. For that reason the access to it is limited by the OS to read-only. So this operation will always fail with an error. Instead you might properly just want to skip seeding the database from the main bundle.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, the phraseology was wrong on that one. I have a regular check that sends the app's database version number to my server and the json returned contains all the items with a higher version number. The highest version number is then saved to the app.

Aa, makes sense. So there is no way to bundle a database and later update that without having a duplicate of the database?

Comment: I didn't intended to nitpick, just checking that this was clear to you how it can achieved. :) But yes, it's correct that you have some inevitable duplication in that use case. The cost might be though negotiable depending on the size of an average entry, so that you might prefer bundling a realm file to retain a seamless UX to your users without upfront waiting time on first usage.